# Call another activity from spinner using Onitemselect Listener.

Tags: android, android-widget

I am new to android.

In android is it possible to call another class or xml in spinner using `onItemselectedListener`.

Comment: Please tell what you are trying to do, and share some code which you have tried.

Comment: @user1360270 Post some code and what you have tried otherwise your question will close by moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
  mList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            // start ur activity

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call another activity when an item is selected from the spinner, first you need override the `onItemSelected()`,

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            // Create the intent to start new activity
            Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, NextActivityName.class);
            i.setflags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call another activity from spinner using Onitemselect Listener. Yes.